# Could we lower the review queue alert threshold?

Tags: feature-request, review-queue

Since the new top bar, we have to click on the review button to know if there are reviews on the queue, but there is no indication before clicking on it.

[image]

Some sites need to have a high threshold because of their high activity, but our activity is quite low so we can have a lower threshold, for example, the review queue indicator starts at 3 review...

Comment: Related: [this general question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302180/162011) as well as the proposal in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302228/162011).

Comment: @MajorTom thanks. Good idea for small sites.

Answer (score -1):

The review indicator, IMO, is a response to The Great Review Panic of '14.  At one point there were over 100,000 items in the review chain.  Commando squads were formed to attack and repel, attack and repel, and eventually the war was won over the 1's and 0's.

A comical tale, yes, but also about 99% true.

On MusicFans, we really don't have any danger of ever reaching a queue that large.  It's just as easy to click a button and see a number than can be wiped out in less than 10 minutes by one person.  Look at it as a Christmas present you can open year-round.

I can't see changing the settings on a site this low, it's just not worth the effort.